# Why does a rope placed on a double inclined plane is equivalent to placing two blocks linked by a pulley?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string

I was solving some physics problems from my High School physics book when I came across with this question:

> A homogeneous flexible rope rests on a wedge such as its midpoint lies on the upper rib of the wedge. If α<β, with what acceleration should the wedge be pulled along the horizontal plane in order to prevent the displacement of the rope with respect to the wedge? [Consider all surfaces to be smooth]

Here's the figure:

[image: Alpha and Beta are the angles that the wedge makes with the horizontal]

I couldn't solve it, so I checked the solution. It uses the fact that the system is equivalent to two blocks, each in one side of the wedge, with the same mass linked by a rope and a pulley. Why is that true? What property of ropes makes it possible to state that? I simply don't get how a single rope was transformed into two different blocks. I can understand how the problem is solved from the point that it is transformed in two blocks on the double inclined plane, but I don't know how it was done and neither when can I do this.

[image: Two blocks on the wedge]

If possible I would like to know if there's a way to solve it without doing this, just using the rope "as it is".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to this question is noting that the rope is homogenous, that is, its linear mass density is a constant. We're also given the distribution of the string on either side of the top of the triangle: it lies on the *midpoint*.

This should make it trivial to see that the mass of the string on either side will be the same. If you want to prove it rigorously, assume the linear mass density is $µ$, length of string is $L$, mass of string is $M$. Then multiply this by the length on either side, $\frac L2$, and the mass will come to be $\frac M2$, equal on both sides.

We can then assume this to be two blocks of masses  $\frac M2$ connected by a light inextensible string and solve.

You can only use this technique when you know the both linear mass density (either as a constant or function), and the distribution of the string on either side of the top point, allowing you to find the mass.

As to your question about using the rope 'as is', the 'transformation' we're doing here is equivalent to treating both sides of the rope as separate point particles and solving using Newton's Second Law. No matter which technique you use, it'll boil down to this basic technique.